# Connect Azure storage through Proxy .net core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am getting error while connecting to azure storage.
Error:Retry failed after 6 tries.
(No such host is known. (shipfiles.blob.core.windows.net:443))

string downloadFilePath = @"C:\test.xlsx";
try
{

```
        string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey=HulI9Usin8D/PgATIYW3FQHS9yyxCB+zLVQCAb4MWq0fEyU63SZIyr9JtzI0iy1K/2Nur0dWyCgeSrknSe/aA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);            
        string containerName = "samplecontainer";
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        string filename = "TACSNTNA.xlsx";
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(filename);                
        BlobDownloadInfo download = blobClient.Download();            
        using (FileStream downloadFileStream = new FileStream(downloadFilePath,FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
             download.Content.CopyToAsync(downloadFileStream);
            downloadFileStream.Close();
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: If you want to know to configure proxy, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/azure-sdk-configure-proxy?tabs=cmd

Comment: I have set proxy on my machine.Stil it gives me the same error.

Comment: Could you please access azure blob via browser?

Comment: I could use it by adding below code. System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", "http://username:password@1.0.0.0:8080");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code and use proxy to make call.

I could use it by adding below code. System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", "username:password@1.0.0.0:8080");